# how to reformat data with dynamic number of columns

Tags: python, bash, text-parsing

I have data in a form that the category and values come in the same line separated by a ";" as follows:

```
{{category1;value}, {category2;value}, {category3;value} ....}}
```

On each line the data is such that there may be different number of categories. So, the first line may have category1 to category5 while the second may have category1 to category10. The categories always come in order though.

I need to parse the data and create a new file such that I have the name of the category in the column header and the value in the corresponding row.

```
category1        category2        category3       category4    ....
 value             value             value          value
```

But since I cannot say how many categories there might be, I need to add each new column as it comes. So, parsing the first line I would know there are 5 columns (cat1 to cat5) but for the second row I have to add the columns for cat6 to cat10 and so on.

Any idea how to do this. Any Linux bash script would do but python would be preferable to me.

Comment: Can the categories or values contain braces?

Comment: @unutbu the values can have any character. but there are braces around the category;value pair also as shown.

Comment: If the `value` can contain any character, what rule should be used to determine that `{{category1;value}, {category2;value}}` is not parsed as having one category, `category1`, with value `value}, {category2;value`?

Comment: that is another tricky bit. I am looking at it such that any pair can be found by looking at the beginning { and then looking for }, to end that pair. lets assume there aren't any characters that end with }, in value.

Comment: So should `{{category1;val},{ue}}` be a syntax error, or should it be parsed as having category `category1` with value `val},{ue`? If the latter, then I think the problem becomes quite hard.

Comment: yes that would be a syntax error. the first case is category1 with value val but the second case wouldn't be valid. simply saying the closed } followed by , and {, i.e. },{ should split the two.

Answer (score 1):

Given the comments, it sounds like the `category` can contain any character other than a semicolon and a `value` can contain any character other than a closing brace, since these characters would terminate the `category` or `value` too soon.

In that case, a regular expression can be used to match the pattern.

```
import re

def report(text):
    # Remove surrounding whitespace and braces
    text = text.strip()[1:-1]   
    pairs = re.findall(
        r'''\{      # literal open brace
            (.+?)   # one-or-more characters, stop at the first
            ;       # literal semicolon
            (.+?)   # one-or-more characters, stop at the first
            \}      # literal closed brace
            ''', text, re.VERBOSE)
    categories, values = zip(*pairs)
    widths = [max(map(len, item)) for item in pairs]
    fmt = '{x:^{w}}'
    for row in (categories, values):
        print('    '.join([fmt.format(x = x, w = w) for x, w in zip(row, widths)]))

tests = """\
{{category1;value}, {category2;value}}
{{category1;value}, {category2;value}, {category3;value}}
{{categ{,ory1;val;ue}, {category2;val{ue}, {category3;value}}
""".splitlines()

for test in tests:
    report(test)
```

yields

```
category1    category2
  value        value  
category1    category2    category3
  value        value        value  
categ{,ory1    category2    category3
  val;ue        val{ue        value
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be number of ways to do it, but a possible way is

```
>>> rows = data.translate(None,"{}").replace(";",",").split(",")
>>> rows[::2]
['category1', ' category2', ' category3']
>>> rows[1::2]
['value', 'value', 'value']
```

and a small variation from above

```
>>> rows = dict(e.split(';') for e in data.translate(None,"{}").split(","))
>>> rows.keys()
['category1', ' category2', ' category3']
>>> rows.values()
['value', 'value', 'value']
```

and yet another variation using regex

```
>>> rows = re.split("[\{\},; ]+",data)[1:-1]
>>> rows[::2]
['category1', 'category2', 'category3']
>>> rows[1::2]
['value', 'value', 'value']
```